# Why the syntax of linking symbols is error

Tags: gcc, linker, symbols

I used arm-none-eabi-ld (GNU ld (2.34-4ubuntu1+13ubuntu1) 2.34) with `--just-symbols=symbolfile`  which includes following symbols.

```
a =0x00000050;
b =0x00000054;
c =0x00000058;
d =0x00001000;
e =0x00001004;
f =0x00001008;
g =0x00000060;
h =0x00000064;
i =0x00000068;
j =0x0000100c;
k =0x00001010;
l =0x00001014;   <--- line 12
m =0x0000005c;
```

If I added symbol "l" , it will output error as following.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld:mcu1_.symtab: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
arm-none-eabi-ld:mcu1_.symtab:12: syntax error
```

But It's ok, if I used `--defsym l=0x00001014`

Does any prefix that I should add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite hidden in the GNU `ld` documentation. Section [**Symbol Names**](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Symbols.html) says: *Unquoted symbol names must not conflict with any keywords.* Sadly, there's no list of keywords. But, Section [**MEMORY Command**](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html#index-l-_003d) says: *The keyword
`LENGTH` may be abbreviated to `len` or `l`.* (There's also an index entry `l =`.) Apparently, `l` is a keyword. So you could write e. g. `"l" = 0x00001014;`.